# Web server doesn't detect script tag with src

Tags: javascript, html, webserver, phaser-framework

Quick comment: I'm a newbie at JS and HTML, so this question might be really simple, but I haven't found an answer so far.

I am using the [Ourcade Phaser template for JS](https://github.com/ourcade/phaser3-parcel-template) to build a game. Yesterday, the web server was able to serve the Phaser Canvas fine, but overnight, without any changes to the code, the webserver couldn't access main.js from index.html on the same level. I know this because a) the Phaser canvas did not load and b) the console window running the webserver said it was only monitoring one file (index.html) for changes, as opposed to earlier, when it was monitoring five, including my Javascript. Neither the webserver built in to the template, the VS Code Live Server extension, nor the python webserver from the command line were able to access main.js and open the phaser canvas, so I'm certain it's not a problem with the Ourcade template. My code for index.html is below:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My New Platformer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is essentially the same code that came with the template.
Is there anything wrong with my code, or is there another problem that I haven't seen? How can I solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Your code is fine as there is not much to worry about. The problem that you are having is probably related to the webserver itself. If the javascript files are in the same folder as `index.html` than it isn't the client side.

Comment: @imvain2, I tried three webservers, and none of them worked. Any suggestions on what I should try next?

Comment: It could be a permissions issue on the main.js file. I'm not super familiar with Microsoft development though.

Comment: @CharlesBamford There are no permissions issues as far as I can tell.